# meta_search conflicting with texticle search gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search, texticle

I use the active_admin gem which requires the meta_search gem and noticed it conflicts with texticle as they both use the search method and it breaks as a result. I read in a few places about similar problems involving solr where they were able to user an alternative method solr_search but I found no such luck using texticle.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `relation' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation):
```

Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Comment: about to have the same issue...I'm thinking about branching the gem and re-naming the method to pg_search since it is postgres specific